# How to install system font for Brackets?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Adobe Brackets editor and I want to know how I can install common fonts such as Arial and Helvetica. I want to directly install them into my system and not just link them into my projects every time. How can I get this done?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Brackets can *only* use fonts installed on your system. I've no idea what you mean by "link to them into my projects" or what Twitter Bootstrap has to do with the configuration of your text editor..

Comment: If you no idea what i mean most likely you missed the point. I want to be able to use helvetica as a font-family. Not monospace. not cursive. not fantasy. Where are all these fonts located so I can download helvetica into my system along with monospace, cursive, and fantasy fonts.

Comment: Questions asking for external resources are off-topic for Stackoverflow, so you can't ask where to download Helvetica here. Monospace, cursive, and fantasy aren't fonts, they are generic categories of font.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for Google Fonts. Google hosts hundreds of high-quality, free, fonts that you can use in your web project. GoogleFonts acts as a CDN, allowing your project to download the required fonts *as the page is being rendered*, similar to how jQuery etc operate when referenced from a CDN.

HOWEVER, you can also download and install Google's FREE, OPEN-SOURCE fonts on your local system and use them locally in your apps, including Brackets. Here is a tutorial for doing that.

[How To Install Google Fonts on your Own Computer](https://www.labnol.org/software/google-fonts-on-computer/19780/)

---

To be complete, here are a couple of decent resources for learning how to use Google Fonts CDN-Style (not what you requested, but for future purposes):

[CSS Reset - How To Use Google Fonts](https://cssreset.com/how-to-use-google-fonts/)

[W3 Schools - Use the Try It beside the font you desire](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_google_fonts.asp)

[CodeCourse 3-Min Video Tutorial (if you prefer video demo)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67AbASjp0co)

The second reference is probably most helpful as it shows you (in their typeface) the fonts that are available, and the `Try It` button shows you a code example for using that font. Straight-forward and simple.

---